# remove date from the reviews (comments) section in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to know how I can remove date from the reviews (comments) section in magento. I have tried removing the date code many time from the back-end, but still it is showing the date.

Comment: can you use template path hints and check which file is reason to display date, so that you can remove it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

The elements you want to hide are of class .review-meta

If you're happy just to hide them rather than remove the code completely, simply add the following style to your css:

```
   .review-meta{
     display:none;
   }
```

Alternatively, if you wish to completely remove the relevant code then copy the folder from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review into your custom layout directory (eg. app/design/frontend/rwd/my_custom_layout/template), and then within the copy edit the file review/product/list.phtml as follows:

Remove the following code:

```
 <span class="review-meta">
     <?php echo $this->__('Review by %s', $this->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname())) ?>
                /
    <?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)',$this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?>
 </span>
```